# data source name not found

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc

trouble connecting to postgresql database using odbc connector(x64) on vb.net console application(x64), the error,
http://www.sumarlidason.com/tmp/120312/odbc_capture1.png

```
    Dim ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=myPGSrv;Port=5432;Database=dbDefault;Uid=postgres;Pwd=pw;"
    'Dim ConnectionString = "ODBC;dsn=PostgreSQL35W"
    conn = New OdbcConnection(ConnectionString)

    'Open connection to an instance of the PostgreSQL database.
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim commonOdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand
    commonOdbcCommand.Connection = conn
    conn.Close()
```

Also, I configured the database in the control panel, see here.. 
http://sumarlidason.com/tmp/120312/odbc_capture.png

Answer (score 0):

correct connection string:

```
Dim conn As New OdbcConnection("DSN=PostgreSQL35W")
```

Comment: It is the correct string in this case as the screen shot shows the Data Source Name (DSN) created is "PostgreSQL35W". If the OP wants to connect without a DSN he needs to use "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)}" (note, he omitted the "(x64)").